# No entiendo el siguiente bucle for, javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Hola buenas recién acabe un ejercicio para verificar si un numero es primo o no pero no acabo de entender del todo la solución ya que este bucle no comprendo bien su significado. Adjunto todo el código y lo que no comprendo es la parte que esta en el else. Saludos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var numero = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca el numero que desea analizar si es primo o no: '));
            function test_Primo(numero) {
                if (numero==1){
                    return  false;
                } else if(numero == 2){
                    return  true;
                }
                else{
                    for (var x=2; x<numero; x++){
                        if(numero%x == 0) {
                            return  false;
                        }
                    }
                    return  true;  
                }
            }
            if(test_Primo(numero)==true) {
                alert('El numero ' + numero + ' es primo');
            } 
             if(test_Primo(numero)==false) {
                alert('El numero ' + numero + ' no es primo');
            } 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me imagino que te refieres a esta seccion:

```
for (var x=2; x<numero; x++){
    if(numero%x == 0) {
        return  false;
    }
}
return  true;
```

Si quieres saber si `numero` es primo, creas un bucle de `2` hasta `numero` y luego divides `numero` por cada indice.  Si el residuo `numero%x` es igual a `0` significa que `numero` es divisible entre `x` por lo tanto no es primo `return false;`  Si el bucle acaba sin retornar significa que el numero es primo `return true;`

Comment: Cuando dices creas un bucle de 2 hasta numero .. no lo entiendo.. el resto perfectamente

Comment: Creas un bucle `for` que va desde `2` hasta el numero que le pasaste a la funcion.

Comment: Ahora si, fallo de lectura por mi parte. Saludos :D